# how to replace string after field separater(=) in file and save into same file using awk

Tags: shell

```
cat file.csv | awk -F '=' '{gsub(/n/,"1",$2)};{print}'
```

while replace string with number the = separator vanishing 
file:

```
a=a+b
c=n+m
o/p:
a=a+b
c 1+m
```

but i want o/p like

```
a=a+b
c=1+m
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your script to this:

```
awk -F '=' -v OFS='=' '{gsub(/n/,"1",$2); print}' file.csv
```

The default output field separator is , so if awk touches the record it will change it from `=` unless you specify otherwise.

I combined your two action blocks; there's no need to have two separate ones.

Comment: I was changed my script but this line working in command line but in script not working

Comment: actually i have two files file1=a,1 n,1 and file2=a=a+b
c=n+m ,i have to change in file2 corresponding values of file1

Comment: It's not a good idea to ask about one thing then change your requirement after the original problem has been solved. You should work on this yourself and do some research. If you get stuck with something specific, then maybe you can ask another question. As a general piece of advice, don't put code into comments; it's totally unreadable.

Comment: while copying in to file in loop , file not changing

Comment: copying is not a problem awk -F '=' -v OFS='=' '{gsub(/$var/,"$value",$2); print}' file.csv , instead of string and value I am passing variable but it is not working